# How to send hashmap as jsonObject in post request to own WebService

Tags: java, android

I want to send simple POST Request to my own API and I have tried a lot of ways to do that but I don't have idea how to wrap it into jsonObject.

I want to wrap HashMap with values:
{
"login": "login",
"password": "password"
}
but it doesn't work

API method:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
requestData = None
responseData = None
status = 400
requestDataRead = False

try:
    requestData = json.loads(request.data)
    requestDataRead = True
except:
    responseData = {'error': 'could not read request from client'}

if requestDataRead:
    if 'login' in requestData and 'password' in requestData:
        if requestData['login'] in usersDict:
            if usersDict[requestData['login']]['password'] == requestData['password']:
                responseData = {
                    'info': "OK",
                    'token': usersDict[requestData['login']]['token'],
                    'userID': usersDict[requestData['login']]['userID']
                }
                status = 200
            else:
                responseData = {'error': 'invalid login or password'}
        else:
            responseData = {'error': 'there isnt that user in database'}
    else:
        responseData = {'error': 'empty login or password'}

responseJsonData = json.dumps(responseData)
responseHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = Response(responseJsonData,
                    status=status,
                    mimetype="application/json",
                    headers=responseHeaders)
return response
```

Android class:

```
String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/login";

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("login", login);
    map.put("password", password);

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams(map);

    client.post(urlString, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());


        }
    });
```

I've tried also pass data this way:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams(map);
    params.put("login", login);
    params.put("password", password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's a

```
<String, String>
```

you can use:

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

Comment: ... to get JSONObject from map ... but not for sending and that was the question ...